# Putting marginpar always on the right in a two sided document

Tags: double-sided, marginpar, marginnote

I'm drafting a document using a required style file for a conference, which is a two sided style. (i.e. odd and even pages are different.)

During the drafting process, I like to use the `marginnote` package to put comments to myself and colleagues in the margin. Sometimes I want these notes to appear on the right and sometimes the left. I know that the side the notes appear on can be controlled using `\reversemarginpar` and `\normalmarginpar`.

However, since it's a two-sided document, the side that's considered "normal" changes depending on whether it's an odd or an even page. I don't want that. How can I put a note in the margin that will always be on the right or always on the left, regardless of odd or even pages?

Note that this is only a 'temporary' measure, in that all margin comments will be removed before submitting the paper, so if the solution changes (for example) the running head etc. I don't mind. However, I don't want to remove the style file or use a different one, since it's important to make sure the text will fit within the page limit when the final style is applied.

The following mwe demonstrates the issue, using the `twoside` option to the `article` class instead of a style file. (Sorry it's not quite as minimal as it could be - it seems there has to be a certain amount of text on the page otherwise `\marginnote` just goes mad and positions things randomly, but that's a separate issue.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.75in,marginparwidth=1.4in]{geometry}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
Some text.
{\marginnote{On the right}}%
{\reversemarginpar\marginnote{On the left}}%
Some more text.

Some more text.

Some more text.

Some more text.
{\marginnote{Still right}}%
{\reversemarginpar\marginnote{Still left}}%
Some more text.

Some more text.

\raggedbottom
\pagebreak

Some text.
{\marginnote{On the right?}}%
{\reversemarginpar\marginnote{On the left?}}%
Some more text.

Some more text.

Some more text.
{\marginnote{Still right?}}%
{\reversemarginpar\marginnote{Still left?}}%
Some more text.

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Page 1 of the output looks like this:

[image]

but page 2 looks like this, with the "normal" marginpars on the left and the "reverse" ones on the right.

[image]

(Note: there are some similar old questions, but as far as I can tell none quite cover my situtation. [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62017/how-can-i-place-marginal-notes-always-on-the-right-but-show-normal-odd-even-head?rq=1), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203573/margin-notes-on-the-right-side-only?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102686/asymmetrical-layout-in-two-sided-document?rq=1) could all be solved with a `twoside=semi` option that the third-party style file I'm using doesn't accept, the solution to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108981/marginpar-on-a-fixed-side-of-two-column-double-sided-memoir-document?rq=1) seems to be specific to a two-column document, and the solutions to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472728/marginnote-always-on-left-side-of-the-page?rq=1) seem to put all the notes on the left, so that `\reversemarginpar` cannot be used to put them on the right.)

Comment: Have you come across the TeXFAQ note [Getting `\marginpar` on the right side](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-marginparside), or its hyperlink ["finding if you’re on an odd or an even page"](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-oddpage) ?  A bit of customizing things to your requirements could solve your problem... though it doesn't use the `marginnote` package as such !

Comment: You may want to use the idea in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409960/todonotes-use-only-left-or-only-right-margin : `\makeatletter 
\@mparswitchfalse%
\makeatother
\normalmarginpar ` (the answer below does not always works, e.g. if you copy-pasted many more times `Some more text.
\rightmarginnote{Still right}` over a few pages: some notes will appear on the _left_ instead of the right-hand side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comments to a full answer... here's what could potentially solve your issue:

Define two new commands `\leftmarginnote{...}` and `\rightmarginnote{...}` that would work equally across even and odd pages.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.75in,marginparwidth=1.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{ifthen,changepage}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newcommandx{\leftmarginnote}[2][2=0pt]
           {\checkoddpage
            \ifoddpage
              {\reversemarginpar\marginnote{#1}[#2]}
            \else
              {\marginnote{#1}[#2]}
            \fi}
\newcommandx{\rightmarginnote}[2][2=0pt]
           {\checkoddpage
            \ifoddpage
              {\marginnote{#1}[#2]}
            \else
              {\reversemarginpar\marginnote{#1}[#2]}
            \fi}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\rightmarginnote{On the right}%
\leftmarginnote{On the left}%

Some more text.

Some more text.

Some more text.

Some more text.
\rightmarginnote{Still right}%
\leftmarginnote{Still left}%

Some more text.

Some more text.

\raggedbottom
\pagebreak

Some text.
\rightmarginnote{On the right!}%
\leftmarginnote{On the left!}%

Some more text.

Some more text.

Some more text.
\rightmarginnote{Still right!}%
\leftmarginnote{Still left!}%

Some more text.

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

I changed the papersize to A5, to get a full compact screenshot.

[image: Margin Notes fixed]

Comment: Thank you, this is great! Sorry for the delay accepting it. I hope you don't mind, I edited your solution to pass on `marginnote`'s optional argument, which determines the vertical position of the note. Feel free to revert or change my edit if you don't like that or see a better way to do it.

Comment: Whatever works best for your problem _is_ your answer. In fact I came to learn the `\newcommandx` from your edit-- Thanks for that !